# IBMQProviderError: 'No provider matching the criteria'

Tags: python, quantum-computing, qiskit

Given below is the code I ran on jupyter notebook I have created account on IBM for this project.
Please help !

```
import qiskit as q
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
%matplotlib inline

circuit = q.QuantumCircuit(2 , 2) # 2 qubit and 2 classical bits 
#currently: (0,0)
circuit.x(0)
#now : (1,0)
circuit.cx(0 , 1)  #cnot gate , controlled NOT gate , it flips 2nd bit if 1 quibit is 1
# now : (1 , 1)
circuit.measure([0,1],[0,1])  # map quibit to bits
circuit.draw(output="mpl")  # ascii of circuit

from qiskit import IBMQ
IBMQ.save_account('MY_TOKEN_NUMBER',overwrite=True)  #save your creds
IBMQ.load_account()
#got this as output to prev line of code :
# <AccountProvider for IBMQ(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')>

provider = IBMQ.get_provider(q.providers.baseprovider)
```

Answer (score 3):

The provider is returned from the `load_account()` call and then this is used to select a backend. Backends are selected by passing a string to the method `provider.get_backend()`. Therefore, I believe the code you need is :

```
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')
```

I would recommend having a look in the [README](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibmq-provider) for more information on how to load your account.

Also, when you have saved your account details once you don't need to keep re-saving them, you can simply call `IBMQ.load_account()`.